Alpha-Beta pruning minimax Checkers
This is my AI to play checkers using Minimax and Alpha-beta pruning; however, it seems like the AI which use Alpha-Beta pruning has worse decisions than the one which does not have alpha-beta pruning. My best assumptions are that alpha-beta pruning cut some cases that might seem bad but it is good later on. I worked on my code alone entirely so it might seem hectic.
def terminal(state,turn):
    count_x = 0
    count_o = 0
    if turn == 'x' or turn == 'kx':
        if not actions(state,'x'):
            return True
    if turn == 'o' or turn == 'ko':
        if not actions(state,'o'):
            return True 
    for r in state:
        for c in r:
            if c == 'x' or c == 'kx':
                count_x += 1
            elif c == 'o' or c =='ko':
                count_o += 1
            if count_x != 0 and count_o != 0:
                return False
    return True

def utility2(state): #win or lose
    count_x = 0
    count_o = 0
    for r in state:
        for c in r:
            if c == 'x' or c == 'kx':
                count_x += 1
            if c == 'o' or c == 'ko':
                count_o += 1
    if count_x > 0 and count_o == 0: #X wins
        return 50
    elif count_x == 0 and count_o > 0:#O wins
        return -50
    else:
        if not actions(state,'o'):
            return 50
        elif not actions(state, 'x'):
            return -50

def count(state,turn):
    count_x = 0
    count_o = 0
    for r in state:
        for c in r:
            if c == 'x' or c == 'kx':
                count_x += 1
            elif c=='o'or c =='ko':
                count_o += 1
    if turn == 'x' or turn == 'kx':
        return count_x
    else:
        return count_o
        
def utility(state): #calculate win chance mid game
    #MAX is 'x'
    count = 0
    for r in state:
        for c in r:
            if c == 'x':
                count += 1
            elif c == 'o':
                count -= 1
            elif c == 'kx':
                count += 5
            elif c == 'ko':
                count -= 5
            else:
                count += 0
    return count

def maxvalue(state,depth,max_depth,alpha,beta):
    # print("max = "+ str(depth))
    if terminal(state,'x'):
        return utility2(state)
    if depth >= max_depth:
        return utility(state)
    v = -999
    for action in actions(state,'x'):
        results = result(state,action)
        for r in results:
            v = max(v,minvalue(r,depth+1,max_depth,alpha,beta))
            alpha = max(alpha,v)
            # if alpha >= beta:
            #     return v
    return v

def minvalue(state,depth,max_depth,alpha,beta): #this combines in to a depth first search
    # print("min = " + str(depth))
    if terminal(state,'o'):
        return utility2(state)
    if depth >= max_depth:
        return utility(state)
    v = 999
    for action in actions(state,'o'):
        results = result(state,action)
        for r in results:
            v = min(v,maxvalue(r,depth+1,max_depth,alpha,beta))
            beta = min(beta,v) #BETAAA
            # if alpha >= beta:
            #    return v
    return v

def minimax(state,turn,max_depth):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the state.
    """
    if terminal(state,turn):
        return None
    else:
        if turn == 'x':
            moves = []
            alpha = -999
            beta = 999
            for action in actions(state,'x'):
                results = result(state,action)
                for r in results:
                    new_v = minvalue(r,1,max_depth,alpha,beta) 
                    moves.append((r,new_v))
                    alpha = max(alpha,new_v)
                    if alpha >= beta:
                        return getbestmoves(moves,'x')
            
            return getbestmoves(moves,'x')
        if turn == 'o':
            moves = []
            alpha = -999
            beta = 999
            for action in actions(state,'o'):
                results = result(state,action)
                for r in results:
                    new_v = maxvalue(r,1,max_depth,alpha,beta)
                    moves.append((r,new_v))
                    beta = min(beta,new_v)
                    if alpha >= beta:
                        return getbestmoves(moves,'o')
            return getbestmoves(moves,'o')

def getbestmoves(moves,turn):
    if turn == 'x':
        for move in moves:
            print(move[1])
        max_value = max(moves, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
        result = []
        for move in moves:
            if move[1] == max_value:
                result.append(move[0])
        print("max = " + str(max_value))
        return random.choice(result)
    elif turn == 'o':
        min_value = min(moves, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
        result = []
        for move in moves:
            if move[1] == min_value:
                result.append(move[0])
        print("min = " + str(min_value))
        return random.choice(result)```

I tried a case like this:
    state =     [['x', '-', 'x', '-', '-', '-', 'x', '-'],
                ['-', '-', '-', 'x', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
                ['x', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'x', '-'],
                ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'x', '-', '-'],
                ['o', '-', '-', '-', 'x', '-', '-', '-'],
                ['-', 'o', '-', '-', '-', 'o', '-', '-'],
                ['o', '-', 'o', '-', 'o', '-', 'o', '-'],
                ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'o']]

The 'v' value generated by the one with no alpha-beta pruning seems to be better. I tried using a bot with only 2 level depth minimax and it wins against my bots with alpha-beta pruning. Please help:(

Do you have a specific question?  If you are looking for someone to review and evaluate your code, this is not the correct site.

I am sorry, I have final exam while trying to finish this project. I am still in the middle of trying to find what causes the problem. I followed the pattern of alpha-beta pruning and it allowed my code to evaluate at a further depth than without pruning; however, it achieved worse results. So, if I were to summarize my problem, did I follow the correct method of alpha-beta pruning or does the error lie in my utility function?
